Tengo un problema con el cliente @firma. ¿Alguien sabe por qué no funciona en móviles?
tengo un problema con los dispositivos móviles, cuando lanzo el cliente @firma, no me carga y me salta un error en la consola:
Type: java.lang.IOException
Message: Ocurrió un error al enviar los datos a la aplicación nativa.
Cargo en javascript, desde una variable en php: var data = "<?php echo $binary; ?>";
Cuando cargo el contenido de la variable directamente en base 64, tampoco funciona.
Lo curioso es que carga perfectamente en Windows, firma el documento desde la variable php, pero en móviles reporta ese error.
¿Alguna idea?

Hola, te recomiendo completar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Sin ver el código es complicado ayudar, lo ideal sería tener un [mcve]
